# zero as interfaceindex argument for MulticastOption Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, multicast

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145114(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp), the `System.Net.Sockets.MulticastOption` constructor accepts a interface index as second argument.

'Zero' is not documented, but seems to work, as if the 'default' interface were selected...

Is this expected behaviour?